# Fastest way to insert data in SQL table using the data from same table or any other dummy data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have a table in SQL something like below

```
PersonDetails
{
 ID, // identity column
 Age int,
 FirstName varchar,
 LastName varchar,
 CreatedDateTime DateTime,
}
```

This table currently has around 100 million rows, I need to increase the data to about 1 billion to test the time it would take to create some indexes on this table.
I can use the data from same table to insert the rows again and again.
What is the fastest way to achieve it?

I made a simple while loop in SQL something like below

```
Declare @maxrows bigint = 900000000,
        @currentrows bigint,
        @batchsize bigint = 10000000;
        
select @currentrows = count(*) from [dbo].[PersonDetails] with(nolock)

while @currentrows < @maxrows
    begin
        insert into [dbo].[PersonDetails]
        select top(@batchsize) 
               [Age]
              ,[FirstName]
              ,[LastName]
              ,[CreatedDateTime]
        from [dbo].[PersonDetails]
        
        select @currentrows = count(*) from [dbo].[PersonDetails] with(nolock)
    end
```

But the problem is that this query shows below error after inserting some of the data.
[The transaction log for database 'DBNAME' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6MNc.png)

I can either add some delay in each insert, or reduce the batch size.

What is the best way to move forward here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this database is living in a testing environment, change the recovery model to simple:

[image]

If not, I am guessing you are not able to change the database settings, I will advice to perform the operation on small batches and commit each iteration. It will be something like the following:

```
while @currentrows < @maxrows
begin

    BEGIN TRY;
            
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            insert into [dbo].[PersonDetails]
            select top(@batchsize) 
                   [Age]
                  ,[FirstName]
                  ,[LastName]
                  ,[CreatedDateTime]
            from [dbo].[PersonDetails]
        
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

        select @currentrows = count(*) from [dbo].[PersonDetails] with(nolock)


    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN;
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

        THROW;

    END CATCH;

    -- WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

end
```

and you can use waitfor delay, too in order to allocated to many resources and block the other queries.

Comment: I was not able to change the database properties but I reduced the batchsize to 1 million, and updated the transaction query as mentioned by @gotqn, it has resolved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temp table and then tranfer the date to the acual table

Something  like this

```js
select * into  #PersonDetails from [dbo].[PersonDetails]

Declare @maxrows bigint = 900000000,
        @currentrows bigint,
        @batchsize bigint = 10000000;
        
select @currentrows = count(*) from [dbo].[PersonDetails] with(nolock)

while @currentrows < @maxrows
    begin
        insert into #PersonDetails
        select top(@batchsize) 
               [Age]
              ,[FirstName]
              ,[LastName]
              ,[CreatedDateTime]
        from #PersonDetails
        
        select @currentrows = count(*) from #PersonDetails
    end
    
    insert into [dbo].[PersonDetails] (Age,FirstName,LastName,CreatedDateTime) select (Age,FirstName,LastName,CreatedDateTime) from #PersonDetails
```